# Transformar Stream em array de bytes

Tags: c#, .net

Boas!!

Estou com um Stream de um arquivo ZIP com tamanho de aprox. 450 Mb, e preciso converte-lo para um array de bytes. Para isso, usa-se por padrão o MemoryStream (System.IO.MemoryStream), segue o código que utilizei:

```
Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();

using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    receiveStream.CopyTo(ms);
    byte[] dadosArquivo = ms.ToArray();
}
return dadosArquivo;
```

O problema, que ao usar o método CopyTo, ocorre uma exceção do tipo *OutOfMemoryException*. Pelos testes que fiz, a limitação do MemoryStream é de aprox. 256 Mb de tamanho do Stream.

Algumas informações extras:

- Esse Stream eu recebo via response de uma requisição Http (HttpWebResponse);
- Utilizo o MemoryStream para fazer esse parse, pois foi a única forma que encontrei em minhas pesquisas.
- Em relação a memória, estou utilizando uma máquina com 6Gb de memória RAM, fiz o mesmo teste em outra máquina de 8Gb e a limitação do MemoryStream é a mesma.

Segue o StackTrace do erro:

```
System.OutOfMemoryException was caught HResult=-2147024882
  Message=Exceção do tipo 'System.OutOfMemoryException' foi acionada.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       em System.IO.MemoryStream.set_Capacity(Int32 value)
       em System.IO.MemoryStream.EnsureCapacity(Int32 value)
       em System.IO.MemoryStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
       em System.IO.Stream.InternalCopyTo(Stream destination, Int32 bufferSize)
       em System.IO.Stream.CopyTo(Stream destination)
       em HiperPdvLibrary.Integracao.Api.ApiRequest.GetByteRequest(HttpStatusCode& status)
  InnerException:
```

Gostaria de saber se alguém já passou por essa situação ou tem alguma outra sugestão para fazer essa conversão, talvez fazer esse processo por partes?

Abraços

Comment: Quando é assim coloca partes relevantes do código, fica difícil identificar o que você está fazendo com 2 linhas. Você fez testes com mais memória disponível? Verificou como está a memória nesse momento? Já experimentou copiar em segmentos ao invés de copiar tudo de uma vez? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783870(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Qual e' a origem da stream? E' um ficheiro em disco? O que e' que pretendes fazer com o ficheiro depois de o ter em memoria?

Comment: Coloca o stacktrace também pra ficar mais fácil de identificar o erro

Comment: Coloquei mais algumas informações que possam esclarecer o problema.

Comment: Sabes *á priori* qual vai ser o tamanho do ficheiro que vais receber por HTTP? Ou é variável?

Answer (score 1):

O problema é o seguinte: a `MemoryStream` começa alocando um pequeno buffer (por exemplo, um array de 4 bytes) e, quando o buffer enche, a `MemoryStream` cria um novo buffer com o dobro do tamanho, copia o conteúdo para o novo buffer, e descarta o buffer velho.

Pseudo-codigo:

```
void AddByteToMemoryStream(MemoryStream ms, byte b)
{
    if(ms.Length == ms.Capacity)
    {
        var newBuffer = new byte[ms.Buffer.Capacity];
        ms.Buffer = newBuffer;
    }

    ms.Add(b);
}
```

Portanto, quando o buffer atinge 256MB, e tentamos ler mais um byte, é criado um novo buffer com 512MB - isto significa que, nesse momento, é preciso que hajam disponíveis *pelo menos* 768MB. Isso, à partida, não é problema.

Mas, mais importante, é preciso que hajam 512MB de memória **contíguos**!!! É provavel que o espaço de memória esteja fragmentado e, por isso, a alocação falha.

Nao há maneira simples de resolver o problema, mas sugiro estas soluções:

## Pre-alocar memória

Se souberes à partida que vais receber um ficheiro de 450MB, experimenta alocar 460MB logo no início, para evitar alocações desnecessárias.

```
var ms = new MemoryStream(460000000);
```

## Fazer stream de *chunks* para o destino

A melhor solução, na minha opinião, é evitar ter o ficheiro inteiro em memória.
Se o objectivo for receber um ficheiro por HTTP e de seguida guardá-lo em disco, podes fazer stream directo:

```
/// <summary>
/// Copies the contents of input to output. Doesn't close either stream.
/// </summary>
public static void CopyStream(Stream input, Stream output)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[8 * 1024];
    int len;
    while ( (len = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
    {
        output.Write(buffer, 0, len);
    }    
}

using (Stream file = File.Create(filename))
{
    CopyStream(receiveStream, file);
}
```

([Código do Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/411605/857807))

Este código vai copiando blocos de 8KB de cada vez para o disco, à medida que estes forem recebidos por HTTP. Assim, a memória do programa nunca vai crescer demasiado.

Answer (score 1):

Boas!!

Consegui achar uma solução para o meu problema. Trata-se de uma re-implementação da classe MemoryStream, chama-se MemoryTributary e trabalha com a alocação de memória de uma maneira diferente que o MemoryStream. No link abaixo, contém detalhes da implementação e um comparativo com o MemoryStream.

[CodeProject do MemoryTributary](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/348590/A-replacement-for-MemoryStream)

Comment: Essa solução consiste em dispersas as alocações pela heap, em vez de alocar um único bloco de memória. Isso é uma solução rápida para o problema - mas é altamente recomendável que tentes fazer stream de chunks para o destino e evitar manter o ficheiro inteiro em memória (se possível). Isso evita problemas que possam surgir quando receberes ficheiros ainda maiores, ou tiveres que fazer load de vários ficheiros em paralelo, ou o sistema do utilizador tiver pouca memória disponível, etc.